# Is there a way to create a user list for adding new users to a simple game using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple game (dice roll) that allows you to add multiple users and I'm running into a few problems. Right now my problem is I can't get the list to output correctly from the nested loop. (I know the value needs to be printed but I'm a bit stuck)

```
import random
import time

def game_start():
    welcome = input("Welcome new user, would you like to play a game?")

    if welcome in ('y', 'yes', 'YES', 'Y'):
        print("Let's begin...")
        time.sleep(1)
        users = login()
        players = game(users)
    else:
        print("What a drag...")


def login():
    while True: 
        try:
            user_count = int(input("Enter the number of users that wish to play..."))
            time.sleep(1)
            print("The number of user is: ", user_count)

            username = []

            for i in range(1,user_count + 1):
             username.append(input(f"What is player {i} name?"))
             print(f'Welcome, {username} you have been successfully logged in.')

        except ValueError:
            print("Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...")

def game(users):
    print(f'This is returning the list of players {users}')

def roll():
    die1 = random.randit(1,6)
    die2 = random.randit(1,6)
    change = 10 if (die1 + die2) % 2 == 0 else -5
    points = die1 + die2 + change
    if die1 == die2:
        points += randit(1,6)
    return points


def main():
    game_start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected results: List to be printed "This is returning the list of players"
Actual Results: Stuck in the while loop

Comment: You never break out of the while loop

Comment: You don't appear to be exiting the while loop at any point, you just have it set to while True and never tell the computer to break out of it

Comment: There are a few weird things here. Number one, you have no exit condition for your while loop. While(true) will always be true, and therefore it will continually ask for you to enter users. 

The second thing I notice instantly is you have no return statement for the login function. This means that your game_start() method variable for users will always be null. This will prevent your game(users) method from working

Comment: If I use the return to break out of my while loop it doesn't return the values that I need. I've tried a similar method before without having to break out an it has work. However when I'm using list it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there appears to be two issues. Number 1 being that you have an infinite loop inside of the `login()` function. While(true) will always be true. In the code below I separated out the function for retrieving user input for the number of users into its own function. This function makes use of the fact that python does not have explicit typing (meaning you can change types of the same variable).

The second issue is that you do not return anything from your `login()` function. This means that inside of the `game_start()` function, the line `users=login()` will always be null. This will make your next line fail, as you do not have a list of users. I have added the return statement below.

**As close to the original posted solution**

```
def login():
    while True: 
        try:
            user_count = int(input("Enter the number of users that wish to play..."))
            print("The number of user is: ", user_count)

            username = []

            for i in range(1,user_count + 1):
             username.append(input(f"What is player {i} name?"))
             print(f'Welcome, {username[i-1]} you have been successfully logged in.')
            return username

        except ValueError:
            print("Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...")
```

**Old Way of Solving by utilizing non-explicit typing**
**========================================**

```
def getUserCount():
    user="NULL"
    while(type(user)!= int):
        userTemp=input("Enter the number of users that wish to play: ")
        try:
            user=int(userTemp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...")
    return user

def login():
    user_count=getUserCount()
    print("The number of user is: ", user_count)
    username = []
    for i in range(1,user_count + 1):
        username.append(input(f"Enter player {i} name: "))
        print(f'Welcome, {username} you have been successfully logged in.')
    return username
```

Here is an example output with just these two functions:

```
>>> login()
Enter the number of users that wish to play: nope
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: not
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: gonna
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: work
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: 3
The number of user is:  3
Enter player 1 name: one
Welcome, ['one'] you have been successfully logged in.
Enter player 2 name: two
Welcome, ['one', 'two'] you have been successfully logged in.
Enter player 3 name: three
Welcome, ['one', 'two', 'three'] you have been successfully logged in.
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

As you can see, printing username inside of the login() function prints the whole array, and is not desired i'm sure. I have fixed that issue with the `login()` definition below.

```
def login():
    user_count=getUserCount()
    print("The number of user is: ", user_count)
    username = []
    for i in range(1,user_count + 1):
        username.append(input(f"Enter player {i} name: "))
        #username[i-1] since i starts at 1 and not 0
        print(f'Welcome, {username[i-1]} you have been successfully logged in.')
    return username
```

provided sample output:

```
>>> login()
Enter the number of users that wish to play: strings?
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: *@#
Oops! That was no vaild number. Try again...
Enter the number of users that wish to play: 3
The number of user is:  3
Enter player 1 name: one
Welcome, one you have been successfully logged in.
Enter player 2 name: four
Welcome, four you have been successfully logged in.
Enter player 3 name: seven
Welcome, seven you have been successfully logged in.
['one', 'four', 'seven']
```

Comment: @TokenThinker No problem. Any questions about what I've shared let me know! I check SO Monday through Friday at different times throughout the day. I may be able to come up with a solution without utilizing the type-changing allowed by python if that would be preferred, but will take a bit more time than I have at the moment.

Comment: @TokenThinker

Actually I just realized it is rather simple to fix your issue. You simply needed a return statement, and not a lot of extra work for the typing of user input.

Adding in the closest original change now